# Passing self to another object? cpp

Tags: c++

Basically making a board game, and I want the class player to roll the die, and then move itself around the board, by telling first the tile it is on, that it is leaving, then telling the tile it is on to move it along the board. (It is based on a UML already given.)

I want to say, make the tile `isOn` move (player, Dice d,in remaining)
But as I am saying this from the player, I have no identifiers?

```
void Player::move ( Dice *d)

    {
        d->roll();
        isOn->move(??,d,d->gettotalvalue());
    }
```

The tile function i am trying to call

```
void Tile::move (Player *p, Dice *d, int remaining )
```

Comment: I'm kind of questioning why these are pointers at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the current instance:

```
isOn->move(this, d, d->gettotalvalue());
```